# Uikit - making each panel the same height/width?

Tags: uikit, height, width, panels

Can someone help me out here - how do I take the following that I have put together and make each image panel where I have band logos the same height and width? Still very very new to uikit so having trouble following online docs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>4WAPEX3</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.css" /> 
  <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js">
  </script> <script src="js/uikit.min.js">
  </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <ul class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-small-1-2 uk-grid-width-medium-1-3 uk-grid-width-large-1-5" data-uk-grid-margin>


    <li>
     <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold "> 
     <div class="uk-panel-teaser"> 
     <img src="images/metallica.jpg" alt="metallica" width="100%"/>
     </div> Metallica
     </div>
    <li>
     <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold"> 
     <div class="uk-panel-teaser"> 
     <img src="images/nin.jpg" alt="nine inch nails" width="100%"/>
     </div> Nine Inch Nails
     </div>
    <li>
     <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold"> 
     <div class="uk-panel-teaser"> 
     <img src="images/tbe.jpg" alt="the butterfly effect" width="100%"/>
     </div> The Butterfly Effect
     </div>
    <li>
     <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold"> 
     <div class="uk-panel-teaser"> 
     <img src="images/tool.jpg" alt="tool" width="100%"/>
     </div> Tool
     </div>
    <li>
     <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold"> 
     <div class="uk-panel-teaser"> 
     <img src="images/tfn.jpg" alt="twelve foot ninja" width="100%"/>
     </div> Twelve Foot Ninja
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</html>
 </body>
```

Thanks